# Force Reload Entire Page That Uses AJAX to Refresh Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, reload

I have a page that refreshes a div content using jQuery AJAX every 10 seconds.

I want to pass a script with the same content retrieved with AJAX to force the entire page to reload whenever I make changes to some CSS/JS of that page.

The page is open all day at the office to 40 agents. I don't want to tell them every time to reload the page.

```
success: function (data) {

    $container.append(data);

}
```

How to safely pass executable JS or a refresh meta tag with `data`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below JS function to reload div :

```
<div id='data'></div>
```

In JS :

```
setTimeout(function () { CallAjax() }, 2000);
```

CallAjax Function :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        url: 'url',
        data: {  },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#data").html(data);
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry you didn't get the point. The code is already functional and it refreshes the content every 10 seconds. The point is how to pass a page reload code within "data" (which is the callback from the url called with AJAX)

Comment: Can't you add window.reload(); in  returned "data(html)" while DOM ready($(document).ready(function(){ window.reload()})) ?